# Isolating Local Minima

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x) = px^3 - q^2x$ where $p$ and $q$ are positive constants. Find all local minima (if any). We define local minima as the $x$-value not the $f(x)$-value. (If there are none, enter an empty list as your answer.)

I first differentiated to get $f'(x) = 3px^2 - q^2$, and $f'(x) = 0$ at relative extrema. Therefore $3px^2 - q^2 = 0$, so $3px^2 = q^2$, and $x^2 = \frac{q^2}{3p}$. I know that in a cubic, since it overall tends towards increasing, the relative maximum occurs first, then the relative minimum occurs. Thus, the positive root of the equation is where the relative minimum occurs.

However, it seems that the relative minimum, (the grader marked my answer wrong) is not $x = \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{3p}}$.

Did I miss something, or is this the correct answer?

Comment: The answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0: = \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{3p}}$. Then

$$f''(x_0)=\sqrt{3p}q >0$$

hence $f$ has in $x_0$ arelative minimum.